# How to decrease value by all cells in the column in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, tablecell

I am bit novice regarding databases and I will highly appreciate any help given.
I need to decrease all cells by X in one column of a table. Do I need to select the table and the column and use the value as variable like `$value=$value +/- X;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well then simply do so by

```
UPDATE yourtablename SET columnname = columname-1
```

(if your column/cell is of a integer type this works fine)
and dont enter a WHERE CLAUSE (updating all rows)

Comment: Thank you all I did it and it worked. My first ever success with databases.Txs again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
UPDATE tableName
SET colName = colName - 5   -- this will decrease the  value by 5
```

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.